# Macro to paste values from first cell to all blank cells below till end of row

Tags: excel, vba

filtering 3 criterias from coumn1,
filtering blank cells corresponding to column 1 result,
I am trying to apply TODAY formula and paste as values in selected blanks only
but its applying on full range(k7:k818) pls help me to recover from this.

```
Range("K5").Select
        Selection.AutoFilter
        Range("K5").Select
        ActiveSheet.Range("$A$5:$N$819").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=Array( "DANGER", "END", "STOCKOUT"), Operator:=xlFilterValues 
        ActiveSheet.Range("$A$5:$N$819").AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="=END", _
            Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=" 
        Range("K6").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=TODAY()"  (formula is "=TODAY")
        Range("K6").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        Range("K7").Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select_

        Range("K7:K818").Select   
       Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what your looking for.  It put's `=Today()` in all visible cells after filtering using the same range as the autofilter (`K5:K819`) then replaces the formula with the value.

Looks to me like the rest of your code is unnecessary and you should be able to use just what is below.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$5:$N$819").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=Array("DANGER", "END", "STOCKOUT"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$5:$N$819").AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="=END", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="="
Range("K5:K819").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Formula = "=Today()"
Range("K5:K819").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = Range("K5:K819").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value
```

It's also quite easy to make this dynamic if you have a column that you know will always have a value by doing the following...

```
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$5:$N" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=Array("DANGER", "END", "STOCKOUT"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$5:$N" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="=END", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="="
Range("K5:K" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Formula = "=Today()"
Range("K5:K" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = Range("K6:K" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$5:$N" & LastRow).AutoFilter
```

The above code finds the last row with data (in this case it's searching column J) and then uses that to filter the data and then I just added some code to remove the filter.  The last row search must be done on a column that you're sure will always have data.  If it's incorrect change the `J` in `LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row` the column you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer...now I m quite clear on this.